# Ajax for email validation in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to use jquery-rails to check if a email exists in my database. But I can't get jquery set up right into my rails application. My form looks like this :

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:class => "col-md-10 center-margin"} do |f| %>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-label col-md-2">
                            <label for="">
                                Email:
                                <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-input col-md-10">
                            <%= f.text_field :email, type: 'text', 
                                data: {trigger: "change"}, data: {required: "true" }, class: "parsley-validated", 
                                 id: "user_email" %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <%= f.submit %>
                    </div>

<% end %>
```

In my application.js I have the following code:

```
$("#user_email").change(function(){
    $("#user_email").append("<p>Test</p>");
});
```

When I start typing in the email field I would think test gets appended but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

in my application.html.erb I have :

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-rails.js" %>
```

Edit:

This is how my application.js looks like

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#user_email").change(function(){
        var currentVal = $("#user_email").val();
        $("#user_email").val(currentVal + " Test");
    });
});
```

Comment: is your javascript code is inside a (document).ready(function(){ //your code})

Comment: This might be unrelated to your problem, but if you have multiple data attributes, you should do `data: {trigger: "change", required: "true"}`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery change event will occure when the focus of textbox is lost:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dcmT3/

```
$("#user_email").change(function(){
    var currentVal = $("#user_email").val();
    $("#user_email").val(currentVal + " Test");
});
```

## Dynamic controls( that gets added dynamically )

```
$(document).on("change", ".controlClass", function() { 
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(currentVal + " Test");

 });
```

Comment: Still nothing is happening after changing focus to another textbox.

Comment: But should I do anything else then putting this code into application.js?

Comment: depending on your elemen ID, it should work... if you are creating dynamic element you need to bind event to document...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `keyup` instead of `change`?

Also, I think `append` will not work for an input element; you'll be better appending to the containing element (possibly the form, or the DIV the input belongs to)?

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6A5E/) for you

```
<div class="email">
    <input name="test" placeholder="Type text here">
</div>

$("input[name=test]").keyup(function() {
    $(".email").append("<p>Test</p>");
});
```